# Where can I find the option to change the "Declaration" color?

Tags: eclipse

I'd like to change the background color used to highlight the variable declarations. At this moment, I'm only able to change the color used to highlight the variable occurrences.
If you take a look at the image below, you can see that the two kind of colors are very different.

[image]

A guy on the [eclipse forum](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=869559&goto=1488030&#msg_1488030) told me that I have to go to Windows-> Preference-> General-> Editors-> Text editors-> Annotations and I have to change the Declaration option on the right.
However, while he shows to me that he has such an option, I have no similar option on my eclipse version.

[image]

I use his same version

> Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1)
>   Build id: 20140925-1800

What could be the problem? How can I change this color?

Comment: He may have some extra plugin installed that adds this.

Comment: @greg-449 Indeed, it could be an option. So, you don't have the "Declarations" option too? Do you know how can I change it, with or without installing a plugin?